# Keyboard layout per program in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout

I'm an Spanish user with an English keyboard. I have my default keyboard layout defined as "United States - International". This layout respects my actual keyboard distribution, but it has an interesting adition: when i press the ' or ~ button it doesn't write the symbol directly, but waits to the next keystroke and if is an specific letter it generates a new symbol (ex. ' plus 'a' generates á). I can press space next to that symbol to write it directly. To a Spanish user, this is an very useful feature for writing letters like á, ü or ñ.

But I realized that there are a situation where this is a nuisance rather than an advantage: the text editor Vim.

Vim uses letters and symbols as commands. Some of these commands uses ' or ". So, when I try to write it, the letter doesn't appear, and I have to press space (and this doesn't always works, as space can be interpreted as another command) or repeat and erase the duplicated one. I know that the standard "United States" layout writes the symbols straightaway, so I want to use it in that program in particular.

So, my question is: there are a way to activate the Standard distribution when I open Vim? I know that if I open the Vim window and set the layout for it, it keeps for the rest of the session, but I want to know if there are a way to do it automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could cook something up with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)